# Recursive Files list function

Tags: php, file, recursion, directory

I am trying to write a `recursive` `php` function that prints directories and files in them. I know I can use `RecursiveIteratorIterator` of `php` but thats not the point, I just trying to upgrade my skill in `recursive functions` so here is my current code:

```
<?php
function recursiveDir($adr){
    $dh  = opendir($adr);
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
        if(is_dir($adr.'/'.$filename)&& $filename!='.' && $filename!='..'){         
            recursiveDir($adr.'/'.$filename);
        } elseif($filename!='.' && $filename!='..') {
            echo $filename.'<br>';
        }
    }
}
$dir = getcwd();
recursiveDir($dir);
?>
```

the problem is when I call this function, it goes into an infinity loop and I can't figure out why.

Comment: I think I put `while loop` in wrong place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your function, and it works, but i want to come up with these remarks :

```
<?php
/**
  * @param String $adr
  * @param Integer $depth : to show nicely the tree
  */
function recursiveDir($adr, $depth = 0) {
    $depth++;
    $dh  = opendir ($adr);

    if(is_null($dh)) {
        printf ("Can not open this directory %s (may be permission is denied)", $adr);
        return NULL;
    }
    // use upper case for TRUE, FALSE and NULL : PHP recommendation   
    while (FALSE !== ($filename = readdir ($dh))) {
        // it will be easy for another developer what do you want to escape from execution
        if ($filename == '.' || $filename == '..') {
            continue;
        }

        if (is_dir ($adr.'\\'.$filename)) {         
            // use printf instead of echo or print, it lets separating between variables and the formatted message            
            printf ("%s DIR: %s.\n", str_repeat ("-", $depth), $adr . '\\' . $filename);
            recursiveDir ($adr . '\\' . $filename);
        } elseif (is_file ($adr.'\\'.$filename)) {
            printf ("%s FILE: %s.\n", str_repeat ("-", $depth + 4), $adr.'\\'.$filename); 
        // ALWAYS : write/do something in uncatched cases ...
        } else {
            printf ("Unknown Resource: %s\n", $adr . '\\' . $filename);
        }
    }
    // never forget to close an opened resource
    closedir ($dh);
}
$dir = getcwd();
recursiveDir($dir);
```

Comment: I think when you are calling the function inside the function, you can use a it like:recursiveDir ($adr . '\\' . $filename,$depth+4);